# Select inside an insert into.. values(...)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-insert

I have this piece of sql code. It is a trigger that activates when STATE in ORDER_SERVICE is changed INSERTING into a table called sms the sms_number (it's a sequence) and the CODIGO_CLIENTE. I have this:

```
create or replace TRIGGER ENVIAR_SMS 
AFTER UPDATE ON ORDEM_SERVICO
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF UPDATING 
  THEN
     IF ( NOT :NEW.ESTADO = :OLD.ESTADO) 
     THEN
        INSERT INTO SMS(N_SMS, CODIGO_CLIENTE) 
            VALUES (SEQ_SMS.NEXTVAL, SELECT CODIGO_CLIENTE 
                                       FROM ORDEM_SERVICO, 
                                            VEICULO 
                                      WHERE ORDEM_SERVICO.MATRICULA=VEICULO.MATRICULA);
     END IF;
  END IF;
END;
```

It's basically a join. I have `MATRICULA` in `ORDEM_SERVICO` as a `FOREIGN KEY` and in `VEICULO` as PRIMARY KEY. I also have (and need) `CODIGO_CLIENTE` in `VEICULO`, thus the join. It complains however about the select I am doing in the VALUES. Any solution for this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply enclose the `select` with parenthesis:

```
INSERT INTO SMS(N_SMS, CODIGO_CLIENTE) 
    VALUES (SEQ_SMS.NEXTVAL
            , (SELECT CODIGO_CLIENTE 
               FROM ORDEM_SERVICO, VEICULO 
               WHERE ORDEM_SERVICO.MATRICULA = VEICULO.MATRICULA)
           )
```

Also, be sure that the `select` returns only one row and one column.

Comment: That worked but I had already simply declared variables and selected into them, works too, just putting it out there as an optiona aswell!

Comment: @Forget When the `select` statement returns more than one row, this `insert` statement will fail. This is not a vary good way to construct the statement. Would be better to simply include `SEQ_SMS.NEXTVAL` in the select list of the query and omit `values` clause of the insert statement altogether. Secondly in your trigger you are trying to select from a table(`ORDEM_SERVICO`) the trigger is defined on - you will hit the `table is mutating` error.

Comment: It won't return more than one row because it's a primary key, thus there is only one row. About the error, could you explain that better? I compiled and it didn't return any error, will it happen when the trigger "triggers"?

Comment: @Forget If you want to use a `select` query inside another query, you *must* enclose int in parenthesis, always. If you don't, you'll get a syntax error